# Passing a variable into a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure what is wrong with my code.  I keep getting A NaN variable for maxLength.  Am I writing this function correctly?

Helper function I am trying to call:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.countRemainingCharactersHelper = function(maxLength) {
        id = this.attr('id');
        var textLength = this.val().length;
        var textRemaining = maxLength - textLength;

        if (textLength >= maxLength) {
            textRemaining = 0;
        }

        var messageId = id.slice(0, (id.indexOf('someTxtBox'))) + 'someTxtBox';
        $('#' + messageId).html(textRemaining + ' characters remaining.');
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Functions calling to the helper function above:

```
function countRemainingCharacters() {
    $(this).countRemainingCharactersHelper(1000);
}

function countRemainingCharacters(maxLength) {
    $(this).countRemainingCharactersHelper(maxLength);
}
```

Calling to function passing in the maxLength variable

```
$('#samplesomeTxtBox').click(function() {
    countRemainingCharacters(4000);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` will refer to the `window` in your `countRemainingCharacters()` functions as you don't call it with a scope. You can fix that using `call()`:

```
$('#samplesomeTxtBox').click(function() {
    countRemainingCharacters.call(this, 4000);
})
```

Also note that the logic you use to generate the `id` of the element to place the message in is a little off. You could improve it by using a `data` attribute to explicitly set the element id.

Your overloaded method is also redundant in this case as you can take advantage of JavaScripts 'falsy' logic to provide a default value if none was provided. This means that you can convert your two `countRemainingCharacters()` functions in to one:

```
function countRemainingCharacters(maxLength) {
    $(this).countRemainingCharactersHelper(maxLength || 1000);
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/7bs54xe3/4)

All that would be left at that point is to create a key event handler to calculate the remaining characters as the user types.

Comment: Thank you so much Rory!!  I definitely didn't know about the falsy logic.